# Flume Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: hadoop, flume

arun@arun-admin:/usr/lib/apache-flume-1.6.0-bin/bin$ ./flume-ng agent --conf ./conf/ -f /usr/lib/apache-flume-1.6.0properties -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console -n agent
Info: Including Hadoop libraries found via (/usr/share/hadoop/bin/hadoop) for HDFS access
Info: Excluding /usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar from classpath
Info: Excluding /usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar from classpath
Info: Including Hive libraries found via (/usr/lib/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin) for Hive access
+ exec /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Xmx20m -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console -cp './conf/:/usr/lib/apache-flume-1.6.0-bin/lib/*:/usr/share/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-client-2.7.1.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-framework-2.7.1.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-recipes-2.7.1.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/gson-2.2.4.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.7.3.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-auth-2.7.3.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpclient-4.2.5.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpcore-4.2.5.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jets3t-0.9.0.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsr305-3.0.0.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/junit-4.11.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.7.3.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.7.3-tests.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-nfs-2.7.3.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/jdiff:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/sources:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/templates:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.13.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jsr305-3.0.0.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xml-apis-1.3.04.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.7.3.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.7.3-tests.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-nfs-2.7.3.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/jdiff:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/sources:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/templates:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/webapps:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-client-1.9.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jsr305-3.0.0.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6-tests.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-api-2.7.3.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-2.7.3.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher-2.7.3.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-client-2.7.3.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-2.7.3.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-registry-2.7.3.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice-2.7.3.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.7.3.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.7.3.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-2.7.3.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-sharedcachemanager-2.7.3.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.7.3.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-2.7.3.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/sources:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/test:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.7.3.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/junit-4.11.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.7.3.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.7.3.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.3.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.7.3.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins-2.7.3.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.7.3.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.7.3-tests.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.7.3.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.3.jar:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib-examples:/usr/share/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/sources:/usr/share/hadoop/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar:/usr/lib/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/lib/*' -Djava.library.path=:/ usr/share/hadoop/lib org.apache.flume.node.Application -f

Answer (score 0):

It is saying out of Memory error. Please change your `Xmx` value while running the application. Currently, you are giving 20MB by `Xmx20m` and maybe this much of memory is not enough to run this. Change it to higher value say 1000MB like this `Xmx1000m` and see if that helps.

You need to find the right value for this configuration. This can be done if you know the data size that has to flow. If you are unable to anticipate that then, trial and error is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

You can try increasing heap size in your flume command by passing -Xmx512m. If you still face the same error pls try to increase heap size in flume command to -Xmx1000m.